Two questions regarding the space $H_0^2(\Omega)$
Here, $\Omega$ is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with smooth boundary. The space $H_0^2(\Omega)$ denotes the closure of $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ in the Sobolev space $H^2(\Omega)$.
$\textbf{Question (1) :}$ For $u,v\in H_0^2(\Omega)$, prove that
$$ \int_{\Omega}\Delta u\Delta v=\sum_{i,j=1}^2\int_{\Omega}\partial_{ij}u\partial_{ij}v. $$
$\textbf{My attempt :}$
I had already proved the above identity for $u,v\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$. I know that one should now use the density argument and conclude the identity for $u,v\in H_0^2(\Omega)$. But I am not able to do this. Could someone help me in the density argument ?
$\textbf{Question (2) :}$ For $u,v,w\in H_0^2(\Omega)$, define $$[u,v]=\partial_{11}u\partial_{11}v+\partial_{22}u\partial_{22}v-2\partial_{12}u\partial_{12}v$$ and
$$ B(u,v,w)=\int_{\Omega}[u,v]w .$$
Then prove that $|B(u,v,w)|\leq C\lVert u\rVert_{2,\Omega}\lVert v\rVert_{2,\Omega}\lVert w\rVert_{2,\Omega}$.
$\textbf{My attempt :}$
If one could show that $\Vert[u,v]\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}\lesssim\lVert u\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}\lVert v\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}$ then we are done by Holder's inequality. But after some fruitless attempts, I am not sure what to do. I would be grateful if someone enlightens me here.

What is the norm $|\cdot|_{2, \Omega }$?

@DeanMiller $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{2,\Omega}^2=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq 2}\lVert\partial^{\alpha}(\cdot)\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2$.

Are you certain the second question is true? From the generalised Holder inequality you can get $\vert B(u,v,w)\vert \leq C | u|{W^{2,p_1}(\Omega)} |v|{W^{2,p_2}(\Omega)} |w|_{L^{p_3}}$ with $\frac 1 {p_1}+\frac 1 {p_2}+\frac 1 {p_3}=1$, but expecting them all to be $L^2$ seems (to me at least) to be too much

@JackT Yes, (at least) this same statement is given in the book as an exercise that my professor is following.

$\textbf{Proof of Question (2) :}$
By Holder's inequality, for $u,v\in H^2_0(\Omega)$, we get that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left\lVert[u,v]\right\rVert_{L^1(\Omega)} &\leq \lVert\partial_{11}u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}\lVert\partial_{22}v \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} + \lVert\partial_{22}u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}\lVert\partial_{11}v \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)} +2 \lVert\partial_{12}u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}\lVert\partial_{12}v \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}\\
&\leq \lVert u \rVert_{2,\Omega}\lVert v \rVert_{2,\Omega}+\lVert u \rVert_{2,\Omega}\lVert v \rVert_{2,\Omega}+2\lVert u \rVert_{2,\Omega}\lVert v \rVert_{2,\Omega}\\
&\lesssim \lVert u \rVert_{2,\Omega}\lVert v \rVert_{2,\Omega}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
By Sobolev embedding theorem, we get that $H^2_0(\Omega)\hookrightarrow C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ and $\lVert w\rVert_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}\lesssim\lVert w\rVert_{2,\Omega}$ for all $w\in H^2_0(\Omega)$.
Thus, for all $u,v,w\in H^2_0(\Omega)$, we get
$$ |B(u,v,w)|\leq\int_{\Omega}|[u,v]w|\leq\lVert[u,v]\rVert_{L^1(\Omega)}\lVert w\rVert_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}\lesssim\lVert u \rVert_{2,\Omega}\lVert v \rVert_{2,\Omega}\lVert w\rVert_{2,\Omega}. $$

First question: Let $u,v\in H^2_0(\Omega)$ and $\{u_k\},\{v_k\} \subset C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ be such that $u_k\to u$ in $H^2_0(\Omega)$ and $v_k\to v$ in $H^2_0(\Omega)$.
Then \begin{align*}
\Delta u_k \Delta v_k-\Delta u \Delta v&=\Delta u_k \Delta v_k-\Delta u_k\Delta v+\Delta u_k\Delta v-\Delta u \Delta v\\
&=\Delta u_k \Delta (v_k-v)+\Delta (u_k-u) \Delta v.
\end{align*} Hence, \begin{align*}
\bigg \vert \int_\Omega\Delta u_k \Delta v_k\, dx-\int_\Omega\Delta u \Delta v\, dx\bigg \vert &= \bigg \vert \int_\Omega\Delta u_k \Delta (v_k-v)\, dx-\int_\Omega\Delta (u_k-u) \Delta v\, dx\bigg \vert \\
&\leq  \int_\Omega\vert \Delta u_k\vert\cdot \vert \Delta (v_k-v)\vert\, dx-\int_\Omega\vert\Delta (u_k-u)\vert\cdot \vert \Delta v\vert\, dx\\
&\leq \|u_k\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \|v_k-v\|_{H^2(\Omega)}+\|v_k\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \|u_k-u\|_{H^2(\Omega)}.
\end{align*} Sending $k\to +\infty$, we obtain $$\lim_{k\to+\infty }\int_\Omega\Delta u_k \Delta v_k\, dx=\int_\Omega\Delta u \Delta v\, dx. $$ By the exact same argument, we also have $$\lim_{k\to+\infty }\sum_{i,j=1}^n\int_\Omega\partial_{ij}u_k \partial_{ij} v_k\, dx=\sum_{i,j=1}^n\int_\Omega\partial_{ij} u \partial_{ij} v\, dx, $$ so $$\int_\Omega\Delta u \Delta v\, dx -\sum_{i,j=1}^n\int_\Omega\partial_{ij} u \partial_{ij} v\, dx=\lim_{k\to+\infty} \bigg [\int_\Omega\Delta u_k \Delta v_k\, dx- \sum_{i,j=1}^n\int_\Omega\partial_{ij}u_k \partial_{ij} v_k\, dx\bigg ]=0. $$

Thanks. I am embarrassed that how would I miss these simple arguments !!
